# KDE freezes when launching a lot of dockers after updating from Kubuntu 23.04 to 23.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde, docker, 23.10

After updating from 23.04 to 23.10 I keep getting KDE taskbar/window switcher freezes when launching a lot of dockers. At first I have been getting a lot of new networks notifications that were created by docker, so I have disabled that, but it still sometimes freezes, and I had to create hotkey to reset whole KDE. Is there some workaround for this?